# Pull data from CSV for Tech Radar

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create my own Tech Radar based on [Zalando Tech Radar](https://github.com/zalando/tech-radar) and getting it to Pull data from a CSV.

But when I refresh the index.html. It gives me a blank page.

What am I missing here?

```
<script>
function draw_radar(my_entries) {
radar_visualization({
  svg_id: "radar",
  width: 1450,
  height: 1000,
  colors: {
    background: "#fff",
    grid: "#bbb",
    inactive: "#ddd"
  },
  title: "My Radar",
  quadrants: [
    { name: "Bottom Right" },
    { name: "Bottom Left" },
    { name: "Top Left" },
    { name: "Top Right" }
  ],
  rings: [
    { name: "INNER",  color: "#93c47d" },
    { name: "SECOND", color: "#b7e1cd" },
    { name: "THIRD",  color: "#fce8b2" },
    { name: "OUTER",  color: "#f4c7c3" }
  ],
  print_layout: true,
  entries: my_entries
});
}
</script>
```

I am following a guide and it is asking me to wrap the radar_visualization() function with a custom one, that takes an array of entry, to render the transformed rows, e.g. draw_radar(entries).

```
<script>
function toEntry(row) {
  return {
    label: row.name,
    quadrant: ['Bottom Right','Bottom Left','Top Left','Top Right'].indexOf(row.quadrant),
    ring: ['INNER','SECOND','THIRD','OUTER'].indexOf(row.ring),
    link: row.link,
    moved: ['down','none','up'].indexOf(row.moved) -1,
    active:true
  }
}
</script>
```

The guide is also mentions a way to transform a row in the CSV into an entry for the tech radar:

```
<script>
fetch('./data.csv')
  .then(function (resp) {
    return resp.text();
  })
  .then(function (csv) {
    var entries = d3.csvParse(csv,function (row) {
      return toEntry(row);
    });
    draw\_radar(entries);
  });
</script>
```

This is the last part to bring them all together. But when nothing happens when I load the .html

Comment: Does the fetch succed? Does `entries` look as you would expect it to? Any errors thrown? Is the backslash in `draw\_radar` just a typo? Not much in the way of debugging details here

Comment: I am actually following a [guide](https://blog.jdriven.com/2018/10/easily-build-your-own-tech-radar/) 

When I refresh the index.html. The page was Blank. 

So I think there is an error somewhere. I will remove the backslash and remove it and test it again

Comment: Are you checking browser dev tools console (F12) for errors thrown?

Comment: Thank you for the tip!. I found out the reason by browser dev. Fetch API cannot load file. My index.html is not hosted. I got it to work once I hosted the html.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!. I found out the reason by browser dev. Fetch API cannot load file. My index.html is not hosted. I got it to work once I hosted the html.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!. I found out the reason by browser dev. Fetch API cannot load file. My index.html is not hosted. I got it to work once I hosted the html.

Comment: Oh you were doing thsi from `file://` protocol? If hosted means remote host you can also easily set up a localhost server on your machine. Numerous easy ways to do it